# Search in gridview using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my website and I try to apply search on this gridview using `SqlCommand` like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM fish_pay 
 WHERE name = @name 
 ORDER BY code_lottery
```

and it works perfectly, but when I try to delete a row after search it doesn't work, and delete another row, I mean `FindControl` returns incorrect id:

```
 Control c1 = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblid");
```

The returned id belongs to the row that  before the search was in that position (for example if after search we delete second row it deletes second row from gridview before search).

Comment: Has your table fish_pay an autocounter? An unique ID per record? If so just delete the row with that unique ID. If not. Add such a column, and then delete a row using this unique id.

Comment: Are you rebinding the grid after you do the delete?

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting *from the gridview* - the gridview is only **displaying** the data. If you want to delete - delete from the **underlying data store** - the database, file, list of items, what have you

Comment: to user743414:yes i have a unique id and do delete on returned id from FindControl

Comment: to levelnis:yes i do

Comment: A word on GridView implementation: Use the GridView DataKeys property. pkey's should not ever be part of the display. you should never make pkeys public.